# The left cosets of $H$ in $G$ partition $G$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup. Then the left cosets of $H$ in $G$
> partition $G$. In particular, $(1)$ each $a$ ∈ G is in exactly one left coset, namely $aH$, and $(2)$ if $a, b \in G$, then either $aH = bH$ or $aH \cap bH = \emptyset $.

The part $(2)$ is done. My problem is in part $(1)$, I tried this but not really sure:

Let $a\in G$, we have that $e\in H$, so $a\in aH$, since $a=ae$. This shows that $a$ lies in some left coset, namely $aH$.

Now if $a\in aH$ and $a\in bH$, we have that $a=ae=abh$, so $bh=e$ and thus $a$ lies in exactly one left coset.

Am I right?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357195/show-that-left-cosets-partition-the-group)

Comment: You need to show that if some $c\in aH\cap bH$, then $aH=bH$; you can’t look just at the case $c=a$. Also, $a\in bH$ tells you that $a=bh$ for some $h\in H$, not that $a=abh$ for some $h\in H$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, But wouldn't your suggestion answer the second part as well?

Comment: @Hopmaths: You can’t really prove the ‘exactly’ part of $(1)$ without essentially proving $(2)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: At first I thought that. But I also thought there might be a way to demonstrate the cases separately. Could I say that (1) and (2) are equivalent?

Comment: @Hopmaths: No. $(2)$ shows only that each element of $G$ is in **at most** one coset. After showing that, one must still verify that every element of $G$ is in **at least** one coset. Had I been writing the exercise, I’d have made this clear by changing *exactly* to *at least* in the statement of $(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you proved (2) I proceed:

$\mathbf{Theorem  1:}$ For $a,b \in G$ prove that $aH=bH$ iff $a^{-1}b \in H$.

$\mathbf{Theorem  2:}$ For $a,b \in G$ prove that $b \in aH$ iff $a^{-1}b \in H$

Then the following conditions are equivalent:
$$b \in aH \equiv a^{-1}b \in H \equiv aH=bH$$ Since $e \in H, a=ae \in aH$.
Let $a \in bH$. Then $aH=bH$. Thus $a$ belongs to exactly one left coset.

Comment: If you  couldn't prove Theorem 1 or Theorem 2 , tell me. Then I will provide the proofs. To prove the converse part of Theorem 1, you have to use part (2) of your question.